# replace the value in column with small value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column in a table of customers that contains very big numbers like this 7351267613862. I want to replace the value with a small value. For example,

```
7351267613862 => 1
7371867613863 => 2
7351267993855 => 3
```

How can I do this by using SQL script.

Note: this value could appear in the table many times.

Comment: you can use ROW_NUMBER , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

depends on how you want the small number like, anyway, row_number() should do the trick

```
UPDATE D
SET   very_tall_number = small_value 
FROM
(
    SELECT *, small_value = dense_rank() over (order by very_tall_number)
    FROM   yourtable
) as D
```

EDIT : change from row_number() to dense_rank()

Comment: these values are unique such like customer ID but appear many times in the table .

Comment: is this row_number() could work without troubles or make conflict?

Comment: so you want the `small_value` to run by customer ? For each `customer` starts from 1 ?

Comment: Because when I tried this script it replace one value with two different values . What I want is replace unique value this unique value (but smaller than original one).

Comment: change to use `dense_rank()`